# Transfer configuratio log4j2 from xml to java

Tags: java, log4j2

I am having trouble rewriting it to java. Can anyone help me? What should the class look like and can I do in one configuration. Without the use of Spring and without the main class.

Download the path for saving the log file from the database. I know that the loger starts first, and then the base, but this is how it should be in this case.

log4j2.xml

````
<Configuration status="WARN">
   <Appenders>
       <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
           <PatternLayout pattern="test [%t] %-5level %C %M: %msg%n"/>
       </Console>
       <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender" fileName="logs/server1/test.log"
             filePattern="logs/server1/$${date:yyyy-MM}/test-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n"/>
           <Policies>
               <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
           </Policies>
           <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000" />
       </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
       <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="error" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
       </Logger>
       <Logger name="com.test.paf" level="info" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
       </Logger>
       <Root level="error">
           <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
       </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>```
````

What I have now

```
@Plugin(name = "Console", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY )
public class LoggerConfig  extends ConfigurationFactory {

    @EJB
    private static PersistenceLocal persistence;

    static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder){
        AppenderComponentBuilder console = builder.newAppender("Console", "CONSOLE");
        LayoutComponentBuilder layout = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "C4bPaf [%t] %-5level %C %M: %msg%n");
        console.add(layout);


        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicies = builder.newComponent("Policies")
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy")
                        .addAttribute("size", "10M"));

        AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFile = builder.newAppender("RollingFile", "ROLLINGFILE");
        rollingFile.addAttribute("fileName", persistence.getConfigList().get("LOG_DIR"));
        rollingFile.addAttribute("filePattern", persistence.getConfigList().get("LOG_DIR") + "/${date:yyyy-MM}/c4bpafp_log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz");
        rollingFile.add(layout);
        rollingFile.addComponent(triggeringPolicies);
        builder.add(rollingFile);

        AppenderComponentBuilder file = builder.newAppender("FileSystem", "File");
        file.addAttribute("fileName", persistence.getConfigList().get("LOG_DIR"));
        file.add(layout);
        builder.add(file);


        LoggerComponentBuilder loggerDebug = builder.newLogger("org.hibernate.SQL", Level.DEBUG);
        loggerDebug.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        loggerDebug.add(builder.newAppenderRef("RollingFile"));
        loggerDebug.addAttribute("additivity", false);
        builder.add(loggerDebug);

        LoggerComponentBuilder logger = builder.newLogger("comp");
        logger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        logger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("RollingFile"));
        logger.addAttribute("additivity", false);
        builder.add(logger);

        RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR);
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Console"));
        rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("RollingFile"));
        rootLogger.addAttribute("additivity", false);
        builder.add(rootLogger);
        try {
            builder.writeXmlConfiguration(System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext loggerContext, ConfigurationSource source) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[] { "*" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Stackoverflow works best with specific questions, and when you show what you've tried that didn't work. Can you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: @WurmD added code